# CRC32 (Cyclic Redundancy Checksum) to string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If I have CRC32 (Cyclic Redundancy Checksum), then how can I get string from it?

Comment: A CRC32 is just an integer, so anything that converts an integer to a string will work...

Comment: Are u asking how to get the original string for which the CRC is generated?

Answer (score 1):

The question is [ambiguous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambiguous).

If you mean "how can I convert the CRC32 integer to a string?", that is fairly easy.  You can use a std::ostringstream or the sprintf() or itoa() functions.

If, as I suspect, you mean "I have a CRC32 generated from a string and I want to get back to the original string", then the answer is "it is impossible".  CRC is a one-way transformation and there is no way to go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `crc32_value` as an hexadecimal string:

```
char crc32_string[64];
sprintf(crc32_string, "%8X", crc32_value);
```

You were not clear enough what format, what kind of string you want. Look at MSDN to find out which `sprintf` works for you. There are plenty of them with a more secure parameter checking.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way to convert an hexadecimal number to a string is the following :

```
std::stringstream s;
s << std::hex << crc32 /*the CRC32 number that you have computed somewhere*/;

std::string resultString = s.str();
```

Hope this answers your question. Otherwise precise what you expect !